# Power Apps, how to set a variable for all users

Tags: powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I was tasked to make an app for my company that allows it's users to make an appointment at the office to limit the number of people present at the same time.
I have to make it in Microsoft Power Apps.

Can someone give me a hint on how to setup a variable for the user that will stay at that value even after the app is closed. I need them to have a limit of 8 days at the office.

Another variable that I need is how many reservations per day have been done. Same as before it needs to be remembered by the app even when the users leave it, it has to be the same value (330 to be precise) for all the users, and when one makes a reservation, it goes down by one. Another user will then see 329.

Do I need to make a a small data base table and have the values stored there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to make a one row SharePoint list and store your retentive information there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).